# How can I check if a WebView URL is a local file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have this question that is unsolved for me.... I need to check if the current URL of my webview is a local file in the Documents directory of my app....how can I do this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check:

```
[request.URL isFileURL];
```

More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/isFileURL).

Answer (score 2):

Check the URL's scheme. Assuming you have an `NSURL*` instance called `myURL`:

```
if ([[myURL scheme] isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
    NSLog(@"URL %@ is local", myURL);
}
```

Read Apple's [`NSURL`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) specification to learn more about accessing different parts of an URL.

Assuming you have a `UIWebView*` called `myWebView`, you might call something like:

```
[[myWebView request] URL]
```

to get the `NSURL*` of what the web view currently has loaded. Then you can call that object's `scheme` as described above.

Comment: Thanks! What is the URL scheme for my file "index.html" contained in the Documents folder of my app?? :)

Comment: Should just be `@"file"`, not `@"file://"`.

(Also, `-isFileURL` is a bit more concise.)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the file:// protocol in the URL.